# CakePHP Unable to access array in nested model

Tags: arrays, cakephp, model

I have a nested associated model based on

```
Project=>ProjectDocument=>ProjectDocumentSection=>ProjectDocumentSectionVariable=>Codeset=>Code
```

I am using containable behaviour to get a specific array with these elements (for a single project).

I have set up associations for these models in their respective models.

Using foreach I am able to interrogate all the data up to an including the `ProjectDocumentSectionVariable level.`

However, once I try to go to the Codeset level, I get errors.

The pertinent code is:

```
foreach ($project['ProjectDocument'] as $project_document): 
if ($project_document['document_type'] == 1) 
{
    foreach ($project_document['ProjectDocumentSection'] as $project_document_section): 
        echo "<h4><a href=\"P4\">" .  $project_document_section['title']. "</a></h4><div><table><th>Variable</th><th>Full text</th><th>Type</th><th>Format</th><th>Codeset</th>" ;
        foreach ($project_document_section['ProjectDocumentSectionVariable'] as $project_document_section_var):
            echo "<tr><td>" . $project_document_section_var['variable_name'] 
                            . "</td><td>".$project_document_section_var['variable_description'] 
                            . "</td><td>".$project_document_section_var['variable_type'] 
                            ."</td><td>".$project_document_section_var['variable_format'] 
                            ."</td><td>".$project_document_section_var['codeset_id'] ;
            foreach($project_document_section_var['Codeset'] as $codeset):
                foreach($codeset['Code'] as $pcode):
                    echo $pcode['codevalue'].", ";
                endforeach;
            endforeach;
            echo "</td></tr>";
        endforeach;
        echo "</table></div>";
    endforeach;

}

  endforeach;
```

But I get Illegal string offset 'Code', and Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()` at the line echo `$pcode['codevalue'].", ";`

I have looked at the array for `$project_document_section_variable` and I think there is a problem with the codeset array, but I cannot work out why it is doing this.

Here is an example of some output for the array `$project_document_section_variable`:

```
array(
'id' => '32',
'project_id' => '05a',
'project_document_id' => '3',
'project_document_section_id' => '2',
'variable_id' => '2',
'variable_name' => 'Respondent Education',
'variable_description' => 'B1. What is your highest level of education?',
'variable_type' => 'Categorical',
'variable_format' => 'Quantitive',
'codeset_id' => '43',
'Codeset' => array(
    'id' => '43',
    'title' => 'Educational level',
    'Code' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '96',
            'codeset_id' => '43',
            'codevalue' => '1',
            'title' => 'No education'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '97',
            'codeset_id' => '43',
            'codevalue' => '2',
            'title' => 'Primary'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'id' => '98',
            'codeset_id' => '43',
            'codevalue' => '3',
            'title' => 'Secondary'
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'id' => '99',
            'codeset_id' => '43',
            'codevalue' => '4',
            'title' => 'Tertiary'
        ),
        (int) 4 => array(
            'id' => '100',
            'codeset_id' => '43',
            'codevalue' => '7',
            'title' => 'Other (describe)'
        ),
        (int) 5 => array(
            'id' => '101',
            'codeset_id' => '43',
            'codevalue' => '8',
            'title' => 'Refuses to answer'
        ),
        (int) 6 => array(
            'id' => '102',
            'codeset_id' => '43',
            'codevalue' => '9',
            'title' => 'Don’t know'
        )
    )
)
 )
```

You may notice that the codeset array does not have an `(int) 0`.  perhaps this is because only one array is returned for codeset (which is correct, each `project_document_section_variable` has only one associated codeset.

Is there something blindingly obvious I am missing here?

Comment: What relationship type did you use between ProjectDocumentSectionVariable and Codeset models ?

Comment: In "PDSV" model I have $belongsTo for Codeset.

Comment: oops.. didn't realise that pressing enter did that..
and in Codeset I have $hasMany for PDSV.

Answer (score 0):

This line -> `foreach($project_document_section_var['Codeset'] as $codeset):` is making php assign `['id']`, `['title']`, and `['Code']` to `$codeset`.

This line -> `foreach($codeset['Code'] as $pcode):` is making php looks for `['id']['Code']`, `['title']['Code']`, and `['Code']['Code']` which don't exists and raise the error.

Try replacing this:

```
        foreach($project_document_section_var['Codeset'] as $codeset):
            foreach($codeset['Code'] as $pcode):
                echo $pcode['codevalue'].", ";
            endforeach;
        endforeach;
```

For this:

```
        foreach($project_document_section_var['Codeset']['Code'] as $pcode):
             echo $pcode['codevalue'].", ";
        endforeach;
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this suggestion.  Unfortunately, I am still getting the error : Undefined index: Code , and Invalid argument supplied for foreach().. I can see what you are suggesting (I had not seen this approach before, so thanks for that!) but still not working in the way I would hope.